# Сравнить значение по заголовку столбца и полю-ключу в другой таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица, в которой имеются в первой колонке Id, а в остальных колонках различные значения. И есть другая таблица, где первая колонка содержит Id, вторая колонка наименования полей из первой таблицы, а третья колонка значения. Мне необходимо как то значения из таблицы 1 сравнить со значениями в таблице 2. Как это сделать на MS SQL? Примеры таблиц можно запустить и посмотреть ниже. Спасибо)

```html
<p>Таблица 1</p>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Key1</th>
        <th>Key2</th>
        <th>Key3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>135</td>
        <td>124</td>
        <td>758</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>758</td>
        <td>333</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<p>Таблица 2</p>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Keys</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Key2</td>
        <td>758</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Key1</td>
        <td>135</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Это невозможно ни в одном SQL. язык SQL не предполагает использования переменных имен колонок. необходимо переделать структуру БД. например развернуть первую таблицу в вертикаль, что бы значения которые сейчас в отдельных колонках были отдельными строками и в эти строках было поле key, которое собственно и горовит к какой "колонке" оно относится. Если таблицу переделать уже нельзя, то вам надо развернуть ее в вертикаль прямо в запросе, например с помощью unpivot и далее так же как описано в начале

Comment: идентификаторы обеих таблиц связаны?